# AppleScript "Can’t get every note of account"

Tags: automation, applescript, ui-automation

I'm trying out AppleScript for the first time today.

Wanted to start by logging the name of every note in my Notes.app

Here's my script:

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    set mainAccount to the name of account 1
    tell account mainAccount
        repeat with n in notes
            log name of n as string
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

I get an error message:

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    get name of account 1
        --> "iCloud"
    exists folder "Archive" of account "iCloud"
        --> true
    count every note of account "iCloud"
        --> error number -1728 from every note of account "iCloud"
Result:
error "Notes got an error: Can’t get every note of account \"iCloud\"." number -1728 from every note of account "iCloud"
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounts don't have notes, they only have folders.

So the script can be written like this:

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    set mainAccount to the name of account 1
    tell account mainAccount
        repeat with f in folders
            repeat with n in notes of f
                log name of n as string
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```